# How to install Nginx 1.21.3 on Debian 10

Tags: nginx, debian

Could someone explain to me how to install Nginx 1.21.3 on Debian 10 please.

thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to install the latest Nginx 1.21.3 version

**Current Version**

```
Nginx 1.21.3
OpenSSL 3.0.0
```

**Fully Supported OS**

```
(LTS) Debian 9 Stretch
(LTS) Debian 10 Buster
(LTS) Debian 11 Bullseye
(LTS) Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic
(LTS) Ubuntu 20.04 Focal
```

**Install via DEB**

```
apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl gnupg -y
curl https://mirror-cdn.xtom.com/sb/nginx/public.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb https://mirror-cdn.xtom.com/sb/nginx/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sb-nginx.list
apt update
apt install nginx-extras -y
```

**Features**

Everything from Debian / Ubuntu official builds are included, with the following nginx modules being added to full and extras flavor:

```
ngx_brotli
ngx_http_geoip2_module
ngx_http_ipdb_module
Statically built with OpenSSL 3.0.0, so you can use TLS 1.3 even on distributions that don't have OpenSSL .
```

Version info:

> nginx version: nginx/1.21.3 built with OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021 TLS
> SNI support enabled configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2
> -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --with-openssl=/build/nginx/../openssl --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --add-module=/build/nginx/sb-modules/ngx_brotli --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-headers-more-filter
> --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-cache-purge --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-dav-ext --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-ndk --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-fancyindex --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-geoip2 --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/sb-modules/ngx_http_ipdb_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/nchan --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-lua --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/rtmp --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-uploadprogress --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx/debian/modules/http-subs-filter

source: [Nginx.io: A nginx Debian / Ubuntu repository](https://nginx.io/guide.html#what-is-it)

Answer (score 1):

Sandra! Google says, that you should try the following tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-debian-10

;)